# glUniformMatrix2fv on Samsung Galaxy Tab Pro with Android GLES20 -- works on Droid Bionic

Tags: android, opengl-es, galaxy-tab

I'm working on shaders for an android OpenGL ES 2.0 program. This is the error message. I google'd it and found nothing.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: length - offset < count*4 < needed
            at android.opengl.GLES20.glUniformMatrix2fv(Native Method)
```

This works on my Droid Bionic, but not my Samsung Galaxy Tab Pro. The actual line in question reads as follows:

```
GLES20.glUniformMatrix2fv(m_u_texture_position, 1, false, m_u_texture_position_floats, 0);
```

m_u_texture_position_floats is a 2 element array of floats. Anyone know why this is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`glUniformMatrix2fv()` sets the value for a uniform of type `mat2`. `mat2` is a 2 by 2 matrix, so it requires 4 floats.

For a uniform variable with 2 values, the type in the shader code should be `vec2`, and you will use `glUniform2fv()` to set the value:

```
GLES20.glUniform2fv(m_u_texture_position, 1, m_u_texture_position_floats, 0);
```

Comment: what worked was the code in this answer with a '1' as shown below:`GLES20.glUniform2fv(m_u_texture_position, 1, m_u_texture_position_floats, 0);`

Comment: Right, that should be the number of vectors, not the number of floats. Fixed now.